# Connect QGIS to MS SQL Server on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis

I try to add MS SQL Server Tables to QGIS on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I installed `msodbcsql17` and `msodbcsql17`

I configured the `.ini` files

- `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[SQL Server] <br/>
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server<br/>
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1<br/>
UsageCount=1<br/>
```

- and `odbc.ini` :

```
[kplus] <br/> 
Driver =SQL Server  
Server = ip-adress, 1433  
Database=kplus
```

I can connect with isql command `isql -v kplus pdw usr` and query tables.

When I add MS SQL Connection I receive the error :

[image: SQLServer dialog]